# C++11 issues when moving from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, unique-ptr

I'm trying to port my project from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012. In my code I have some file handling that looks like this:

```
auto fileDeleter = [](FILE* f) { fclose(f); };

unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(fileDeleter)> fMinute(
    fopen(minuteLogName.c_str(), "w"), fileDeleter);


unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(fileDeleter)> fIndividual(
    fopen(individualLogName.c_str(), "w"), fileDeleter);

if (!fMinute || !fIndividual) {
    throw Exceptions::IOException("One of the log files failed to open",
                                  __FUNCTION__);
}
```

This built with no issues in 2010, but in 2012 it fails on the conditional with:

> error C2678: binary '!' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type > 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>   ...
>   could be 'built-in C++ operator!(bool)'

The C++11 standard specifies that [unique_ptr has a bool operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool) to allow you to do quick checks like I have above. Stranger yet, VS2012's unique_ptr definition has this very operator:

```
_OPERATOR_BOOL() const _NOEXCEPT
{   // test for non-null pointer
    return (this->_Myptr != pointer() ? _CONVERTIBLE_TO_TRUE : 0);
}
```

But I get that error upon compilation. Why?

Yes, I could just be using `ofstream` instead, but that's besides the point.

Comment: This seems to be caused by using a lambda as a custom deleter. If you use something else, e.g. a regular function object, then there is no issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To build on what BigBoss said, C++11 requires that `std::unique_ptr` use `explicit operator bool() noexcept`, which solves the whole implicit conversion to bool problem. Except... VC2012 doesn't *support* `explicit` operators yet. Therefore, they have to use the [safe-bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

While the safe-bool idiom is good, it can have flaws (which is why `explicit operator bool()` exists), depending on how you implement the idiom. And you apparently ran across one of them in VC2012. Reconfiguring your test, with `!(fMinute && fIndividual)`, should solve it.

But either way, it's a Visual Studio bug. Since the behavior changed, you should file a bug report even if you do manage to find a way around it.

Comment: VS2012 doesn't support noexcept either

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if (!(fMinute && fIndividual) )` instead of `if (!fMinute || !fIndividual)`. C++ say that they are convertible to bool, but `operator bool` usually create problems, for example you may have a function that accept `int`, if your class have an `operator bool` then it is convertible to int and you can pass it to this function, but for example in our case `unique_ptr` never intended to be used as an `int`, so many developers never use `operator bool` directly but instead write an operator that can be used as a bool in conditional expressions but it is not actually bool!

```
struct bool_convertible {
    typedef void (*convertible_to_bool)();
    static void convertible_to_true();
    operator convertible_to_bool () const {
        return test() ? &convertible_to_true : nullptr;
    }
};
```

Using this technique I may have `bool_convertible c; if( c ) {...}` but I can't have

```
void test_int( int );
bool_convertible c;
test_int( c );
```

Comment: Specializations of `std::unique_ptr` are *not* convertible to `bool`. They are however *contextually* convertible to `bool` via the use of an `explicit` conversion operator to `bool`.

Comment: @LucDanton: Technically true, but that changes nothing, since "!" is one of the contexts where things can be contextually convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @NicolBolas That doesn't make this answer any more useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent C++11 standard, std::unique_ptr has no `operator!` defined, only the explicit conversion operator

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

However, the built-in unary logical negation operator, `!`, contextually converts its argument to bool according to 5.3.1/9:

> The operand of the logical negation operator `!` is contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4); its value is true if the converted operand is false and false otherwise

Contextual conversion to bool will use an explicit conversion operator, if available. So, your code is actually expected to work under C++11 rules. You should probably file a bug report to Microsoft. Whether they support explicit conversion operators or not should not matter.

As a workaround try this:

```
if (!fMinute.get() || !fIndividual.get()) {
    ....
```